# run jupyter-dash update without killing kernels

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly-dash, jupyterdash

I am working on a dash project on jupyter notebook with jupyter-dash. Each time I updated my code, I had to kill the kernels and than restart the jupyter notebook in order to get the changing code working. Otherwise the dash webpage shows double loaded errors. I wonder if there is a way to refresh the jupyter-dash server without restarting the kernels?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, now you can do that without killing the kernel. Try to use `JupyterDash` with `mode='external'`. Please have a look at the code below:

[image]